# Scroll to a specific div on a new page using react router dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am currently using react router dom for routing in my react application.  I am trying to scroll to specific div on another page using Link from react router dom.  The issue I am running into is that the page changes yet it does not scroll to the id of the div i have specified.  I am unsure of what I am missing.

my code is as follows:
App.js

```
import { Switch, Route, BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

import Home from "./Home";
import PageTwo from "./PageTwo";
import "./styles.css";
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/pagetwo" component={PageTwo} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;

Home Page
```

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>Navigate to div on new page</div>
      <Link to="/pagetwo#div">Home</Link>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

PageTwo:

```
const PageTwo = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ marginTop: 500 }} id="div">
        Page Two Div
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PageTwo;
```

css:

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

attached is a code sandbox for debugging! https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-hill-0ln79?file=/src/PageTwo.js:0-171

Comment: And where is the code that's suppose to do scrolling?

Comment: if I were to type the id of the div I want to scroll to in the url next to the route it would take me to that exact div, for some reason when i use link or navlink etc from react router dom it doesn't work

Comment: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/394#issuecomment-220221604 have you tried this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of this [issue on github](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/394) use `react-router-hash-link` package.

```
<HashLink to="/pagetwo#div">Home</HashLink>
```

here is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-payne-b6qs1?file=/src/Home.js:180-229)

Answer (score 2):

**1. First install**

```
npm i react-router-hash-link
```

**or**

```
npm i react-router-hash-link --force
```

**2. Then import it and Provide the exact path and id of the component.**

```
import { HashLink } from 'react-router-hash-link';

<HashLink to="/some/path#with-hash-fragment">Link to Hash Fragment</HashLink>
```

***Note: For smmoth scroll add the following.***

```
<HashLink smooth to="/path#hash">
  Link to Hash Fragment
</HashLink>;
```

*Help*: [react-router-hash-link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-hash-link)